# Out of space on EC2 instance due to docker logs

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker

I'm still learning docker and AWS, and I've had a docker process running awhile with 50gb EBS storage, and now I'm out of disk space and as a result, docker no longer starts up when I reboot my instance.

When I try `sudo du -h / | grep '[0-9\.]\+G'` I get:

```
1.8G    /var/lib/docker/containers/f7cf0...
17G     /var/lib/docker/containers/55b7e...
2.8G    /var/lib/docker/containers/987b0...
22G     /var/lib/docker/containers/726b0...
44G     /var/lib/docker/containers
4.3G    /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper
4.3G    /var/lib/docker/devicemapper
48G     /var/lib/docker
48G     /var/lib
48G     /var
0       /sys/bus/mdio_bus/drivers/Generic 10G PHY
50G     /
```

And when I try `sudo docker ps -a` I get:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

I don't want to touch the 726b0... process, that's the most important.  Will it cause problems if I delete the .log file for 55b7e...?  Is there a cleaner way to do that than to just remove the file?

Comment: If you delete that file, the space will still be used since there are open handles to it from running processes. You'll want to truncate the file with `:> whatever.log`

Comment: How about writing the script that continuously look for container not in use..
My 1 cent for that

    docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
    docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)

Comment: I answered a very similar question on SO with a solution I received from AWS support. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50779802/300347

Answer (score 7):

If you're using **Elastic Beanstalk** to run Docker, this may interest you.

I took Yonatan's command and converted it into an `.ebextensions` cron job that will run every X hours, and clear the Docker container logs so that they don't accumulate and clog the server. I had to modify it to use `tee` to avoid an [ambiguous redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505339/bash-ambiguous-redirect-redirect-to-multiple-files) bash error.

Simply create an `.ebextensions` directory in your repository root (next to `Dockerrun.aws.json`) and a `docker-log-truncate.config` file inside it with the following content:

```
commands:
    add_docker_log_truncate_cronjob:
        command: "crontab -l | grep -q 'eb-docker' || (crontab -l ; echo '0 * */6 * * /bin/echo 0 | tee /var/log/eb-docker/containers/*/*.log')| crontab -"
        ignoreErrors: true
```

In this case, the command will run every 6 days and clear your Docker container logs. Note that I was not able to update my Elastic Beanstalk with this change until I terminated all affected servers, probably because Beanstalk needs some free disk space to deploy the new version.

Comment: Am I a noob or is `0 * */6 * *` every six days? I think you want `0 */6 * * *`

Comment: @Yetanotherjosh Good catch! I guess this worked out fine anyway for me as the buildup takes a while to occur, but your solution is most likely preferable.

Comment: Also a couple things to note: EB supports an easier way to add crons by creating new files in /etc/cron.d/, and, I've found my logs actually live in a different location (/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log). Here is my config which is working well so far https://gist.github.com/jwhiting/f703d093a7d8b4fbb3b688139ac08ac6

Comment: Further update: I got a response from AWS support on this issue and have posted a more complete answer on a related SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50779802/300347

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully executed `echo '' > /var/log/eb-docker/containers/*/*.log` on a live production server without any issues, in order to truncate a 5gb log file.

Comment: You don't need the `echo ''`  a simple `>filename` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following section to your Docker run file:

```
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "json-file",
    "options": {"max-size": "100m", "max-file": "10"}
}
```

see documentation for more details: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/